# Genuine Windows Validation Tool will not run

Tags: windows, windows-xp-mode, wga

I am trying to download XP mode, but when I run the WGA tool provided by the download link, it says the tool itself is out of date.

This version of the Windows Genuine Advantage validation tool is no longer supported.  Please download the newest version and ensure that your system clock is accurate

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: did you check your machine's date and time? Is it correct?

Comment: Also you can use the direct download links here that will not require Genuine Advantage check: http://www.mydigitallife.info/windows-7-virtual-pc-and-windows-xp-mode-official-direct-download-links/

Comment: The version of Windows I have is "genuine", so I'd just assume download the stuff direct from MS (as I should be able to do).

Comment: Seems fair. FYI, the link I have shared are pointing to the same Microsoft links that google gives. It is just the links that are available AFTER genuine check. So in a way you just skip one step

Comment: @Ganesh did not realize that, thank you for the clarification.  The links work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem: you now MUST run Microsoft's ActiveX Genuine Check tool, in 32-bit IE. What's even worse, the page which loads it LOADS IT INSECURELY!!!

Good job, Microsoft! This would allow a man-in-the-middle attack to substitute a different ActiveX component.

See http://static.spiceworks.com/attachments/post/0014/8128/Insecure_Delivery_of_Validation_ActiveX.png

Comment: Is not the ActiveX module digitally signed?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand properly... this is the component that have to be downloaded and installed locally, and it clearly stated that the add-in is signed by Microsoft Corporation, so why do you think that this is the "insecure" installation?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error message is because you are using a third party browser like Google Chrome or Firefox.

Normally to validate Windows 7, you **must** use Microsoft Internet Explorer and make sure you have installed the ActiveX plugin prior to your Windows validation (which is prompted automatically). This should definitely work, as it did work for me.